# Poor Regression Model Predicts Correct

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, least-squares

I have the below case study and i need some help

My model is y=1.0527x - 0.082

y= IOS (percentages)
x = Bank Rate (percentages)

Based on the graph in the bottom the model doesn't fit the data due to low R2 and the outliers

However, when we see the back testing (yellow line in the top diagram) the model OIS (2009 -2017) almost perfectly fits the data which i am struggled to understand or explain

If the model is not correct how can correctly predict both periods and especially the 2009 - 2017 (top graph)?

My first thought is that since the Bank Rate is stable we might have violation of OLS assumptions but again how the back testing is almost correct?

Thanks,

Antonis

[image]

[image]